# Potting the 9 ball in a foul shot - what happens?

Tags: rules, pool

I am playing [nine-ball pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine-ball). What happens if I pot the 9 ball as a foul shot?

Either:

- I pot the cue ball with the 9 ball
- I don't hit the lowest numbered ball

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**: The ball is returned to the table and you do not automatically loose

The [National Billiard Association](https://wpapool.com/rules-of-play/#9-ball) has these rules:

> **2.6 Spotting Balls**
>
> If the nine ball is pocketed on a foul or push out, or driven off the table, it is spotted. (See 1.4
> **Spotting Balls**.) No other object ball is ever spotted.

A *spotting ball* is defined as:

> **1.4 Spotting Balls**
>
> Balls are spotted (returned to play on the table) by placing them on the long string (long axis
> of the table) as close as possible to the foot spot and between the foot spot and the foot rail,
> without moving any interfering ball. If the spotted ball cannot be placed on the foot spot, it
> should be placed in contact (if possible) with the corresponding interfering ball. However,
> when the cue ball is next to the spotted ball, the spotted ball should not be placed in contact
> with the cue ball; a small separation must be maintained. If all of the long string below the
> foot spot is blocked by other balls, the ball is spotted above the foot spot, and as close as
> possible to the foot spot.